# EXC_BAD_ACCESS during NSFileVersion call to removeOtherVersionsOfItemAtURL: inside coordinated write block

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using what *seems* to be a simple invocation of the `NSFileVersion` class method `removeOtherVersionsOfItemAtURL:` inside a coordinated writing block for some iCloud conflict resolution.

When my devices go into 'spaz mode', which is a technical term for repeatedly opening and closing the application on a few devices, an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception is thrown internally. Code snippet:

```
- (void)compareVersionChanges:(NSFileVersion *)version {
    if (![DataLoader iCloudPreferenceEnabled]) {
        NSLog(@"Ignoring iCloud changes (version comparison) based on user preference");
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"compareVersionChanges");
    dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(aQueue, ^(void) {
        NSError *readError = nil;
        NSFileCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:(id)self];
        [coordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:[version URL] options:0 error:&readError byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) {
            DataContext *loadedContext = nil;
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:newURL];
            NSError *e = nil;
            loadedContext = [self convertXmlDataToContext:data error:&e];
            if (e) {
                NSLog(@"Done loading, error: %@", e);
                [[DataLoader applicationDelegate] displayError:e];
                loadedContext = nil;
            }

            if (!loadedContext) {
                return;
            }

            id appDelegate = [DataLoader applicationDelegate];
            DataContext *inMemoryContext = nil;
            if (appDelegate != nil && [appDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(context)]) {
                inMemoryContext = [appDelegate performSelector:@selector(context)];
            }

            if (inMemoryContext) {
                NSLog(@"Performing iCloud context synchronizating...");
                DataContextSynchronizer *synchronizer = [[DataContextSynchronizer alloc] init];
                ChangeSet *changes = [synchronizer compareLocalContext:inMemoryContext andRemoteContext:loadedContext];
                if ([[changes changes] count] > 0) {
                    [SelectionManager disable];
                    @synchronized(appDelegate) {
                        NSLog(@"Applying synchronization changes...");
                        [synchronizer applyChangeSet:changes toDataContext:inMemoryContext];
                        NSLog(@"Synchronization changes applied");
                    }
                    [SelectionManager enable];
                    if ([appDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(setSkipRefreshSave:)]) {
                        [appDelegate performSelector:@selector(setSkipRefreshSave:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
                    }
                    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
                    dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^(void) {
                        [SelectionManager notifyListeners];
                    });
                    if ([appDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(setSkipRefreshSave:)]) {
                        [appDelegate performSelector:@selector(setSkipRefreshSave:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
                    }
                    [self save:[[DataLoader applicationDelegate] context]];
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"No sync changes applicable.");
                }
                NSError *coordinateWriteRemoveError = nil;
                [coordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL:newURL options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForDeleting error:&coordinateWriteRemoveError byAccessor:^(NSURL *theURL) {
                    theURL = [theURL copy];
                    NSError *removeOtherVersionsError = nil;
                    [NSFileVersion removeOtherVersionsOfItemAtURL:theURL error:&removeOtherVersionsError];
                    if (removeOtherVersionsError) {
                        NSLog(@"Error removing other versions: %@", removeOtherVersionsError);
                    }
                }];
                if (coordinateWriteRemoveError) {
                    NSLog(@"Error occurred coordinating write for deletion of other file versions: %@", coordinateWriteRemoveError);
                }
            }
        }];


        if (readError) {
            NSLog(@"Done loading (outside block) error: %@", readError);
        }
    });
}
```

I thought a little syntax highlighting might make this easier to examine:

[**Link to image of code snippet and failure stack in Xcode**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hagUk.png)

The error actually occurs on **line 1404**, and as you can see from the below screenshot, it's deep in Apple code territory.

[**Link to image of debugger**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXTDQ.png)

Before submitting a radar, I thought I'd check here to see if there's something I'm doing wrong? The extra `[... copy]` on line 1402 was just a quick check to make sure I'm not losing the reference to the block-provided argument, and will be removed.

**Edit:** An important note! I'm using ARC.

**Edit 2:** I've noticed that when calling:

`[NSFileVersion otherVersionsOfItemAtURL:theURL]`

The return value is `nil`, which indicates (via the documentation):

> ...or nil if there is no such file. The array does not contain the version object returned by the currentVersionOfItemAtURL: method.

So by checking the return value of this method *before* I make the call to `removeOtherVersionsOfItemAtURL:`, it has alleviated the issue. But I still find it strange that an EXC_BAD_ACCESS is thrown, rather than that method handling it properly.

Comment: Why don't you post the code instead of the screenshot ?

Comment: I can't read a thing in that screenshot. If only there was some way to  format code to put directly into a question here . . . ;)

Comment: Sorry guys - I'll edit to include code. The screenshots just seemed easier (for me) to read. You can usually click them to zoom in, but in this case I had to right-click and open in a new tab to get full resolution, I'm not sure why. I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that when calling:

`[NSFileVersion otherVersionsOfItemAtURL:theURL]`

immediately prior to the call to `removeOtherVersionsOfItemAtURL:`, the return value is nil, which indicates (via the documentation):

> Returns: An array of file version objects or nil if there is no such
>   file. The array does not contain the version object returned by the
>   currentVersionOfItemAtURL: method.

So by checking the return value of this method before I make the call to `removeOtherVersionsOfItemAtURL:`, it has alleviated the issue. But I still find it strange that an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is thrown by `removeOtherVersionsOfItemAtURL:`, rather than that method simply returning `NO`, or simply populating the provided `NSError` object.

I'll be filing a Radar and will update here when I hear back.